# Raspberry Pi 4 updated bootloader

Tags: bootloader, raspberrypi, usb-drive

A new beta boot loader (will be out of the beta pretty soon) has been released for the raspberry pi 4 which supports USB boot natively, without the need of an SD card.
Are there any plans for supporting that feature on Ubuntu in the near future?

Comment: there is [this response](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=268476&sid=60e4837ee71ec343b851c86ac9a17af7#p1634061) in a Raspberry Pi forum about "easy Ubuntu SSD Boot" which states USB Boot is being worked on by the Ubuntu team (the author used "we" so it's possible this is even first-hand info) but implies it won't be available particularly soon. Apparently, `u-boot` is a blocker/specific pain point. Also [asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253448/ubuntu-20-04-raspberry-pi-4-b-usb-boot-implementation)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'm looking forward to hearing more news about this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that `Ubuntu 20.10 x64` (and I'm guessing `x32` as well) can be installed on an external SSD to be used natively with the Raspberry Pi 4. To write Ubuntu on an SSD, one should use the Raspberry Pi Imager from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-imaging-utility).