# Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi 4 B USB Boot Implementation

Tags: boot, 20.04, bootloader, raspberrypi, usb-drive

this is basically a repeat of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242808/raspberry-pi-4-updated-bootloader) from a month ago with more detail

On 15 June 2020 Raspberry Pi promoted the USB Mass Storage Boot functionality for Raspberry Pi 4s to "stable". Raspberry Pi users are still required to edit which firmware they'd like to load from "critical" to "stable" but it is an otherwise readily available feature.

**Biggest question:** What is the timeline for Ubuntu to support the newly promoted "stable" firmware which allows for USB Boot?

**Alternatively,** has anyone sussed out the right configuration edits to make to force it? I was able to get to a `U-Boot>` failure point after having copied `start4.elf` and some other config files from a USB-booting Raspberry Pi Buster install but cannot seem to get past the `U-Boot>` error where it seems to not be finding my devices or ethernet.

Any information on expected timeline for getting USB boot into the official imager *or* assistance getting with a bootable configuration to an Ubuntu 20.04 imaged installation would be much appreciated

Thanks!

EDIT: there is [this comment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=268476&sid=60e4837ee71ec343b851c86ac9a17af7#p1634061) from what appears to be someone on the Ubuntu team. No timeline is given and the implication seems to be it won't be anytime particularly soon.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled from source code U-Boot 2020.10-rc4-00027-g4dcced1169
(https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot)
successfully boots from USB mass storage device.
Also it supports Raspberry Pi 4B built-in Ethernet.

```
U-Boot 2020.10-rc4-00027-g4dcced1169 (Sep 16 2020 - 07:00:33 +0000)

DRAM:  3.9 GiB
RPI 4 Model B (0xc03111)
MMC:   mmcnr@7e300000: 1, emmc2@7e340000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... Card did not respond to voltage select!
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   eth0: ethernet@7d580000
PCIe BRCM: link up, 5.0 Gbps x1 (SSC)
starting USB...
Bus xhci_pci: Register 5000420 NbrPorts 5
Starting the controller
USB XHCI 1.00
scanning bus xhci_pci for devices... 3 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 1 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
U-Boot> 
U-Boot> usb tree
USB device tree:
  1  Hub (5 Gb/s, 0mA)
  |  U-Boot XHCI Host Controller 
  |
  +-2  Hub (480 Mb/s, 100mA)
    |   USB2.0 Hub 
    |
    +-3  Mass Storage (480 Mb/s, 200mA)
         SanDisk Cruzer Facet 4C532000040726111220
```